# Tibetan keyboard

Tags: keyboard, language-support

I'm trying to set up a Tibetan keyboard in Ubuntu 20.04. I've installed a standard Tibetan font. I've set the ibus (intelligent input bus) preferences, adding a Tibetan input method there as well as hotkey for changing keyboards.

But Tibetan doesn't appear in the list of available installed languages under Region and Languages in Settings, and this is apparently necessary to get a Tibetan keyboard.

Is it possible to add a language to the list of installed languages?

Comment: How did you install a Tibetan input method? I would suggest that you install the `ibus-m17n` package and relogin. Then you should see a few Tibetan options in Region & Language.

Comment: Thank you! I had installed ibus-m17n. I also selected an input format (ewts) in ibus preferences. I relogged-in (and restarted), but Tibetan still didn't show up in Region and Language. Dzongka (Bhutanese Tibetan) is available, but that keyboard is unacceptable. I may somehow have installed m17n improperly?

Comment: Solved! (by my husband) There are three dots under 'Input sources' in Region and Languages that I didn't see. If your language isn't listed but you have the package for it, you should be able to get it by typing it in under 'Other'

Comment: Ah, great. Can say that you are not exactly the first user who had a problem with the Region & Language GUI in this respect. :/ (Adding sources in `ibus-setup` does not make a difference on a GNOME desktop, btw.)

Comment: Huh - that's confusing about ibus setup. The online resources for Tibetan researchers etc aren't keeping up.

Comment: The resources you found may well be correct. The thing is that GNOME works differently compared to other desktop environments in this respect.